# How to resolve app:mergeDebugResources error to run the app on the emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I've tried to run my app on the emulator but then the app:mergeDebugResources error appears and i can't run it.

I just want to run my app on the emulator, please help.

Comment: Please post errors as text rather than screenshots. We can't even see the full error in this. To paste a trace, highlight it in the IDE, copy it, then paste it in the question editor. Highlight it in the editor and press Ctrl+K to format it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix the filename of `cinta4 - copia.png` ... because dashes and spaces are illegal for resource descriptors, use `_` underscore; eg `cinta4_copia.png`... and please don't post screenshots; when having copied and pasted the error log, you probably would have seen the suggestion to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but now i have an :app:processDebugResources error i'll look in another post to fix it. And thanks, because i didn't know about the column wich describes the error, i won't post the errors in screenshots.

Comment: @cristianoronaldo when looking at the logs, this often (almost always) tells one what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check the error, specifically the line containing

```
Caused by: C:\Users\ninos.NINOS\AndroidStudioProjects\Botones\app\src\main\res\drawable\cinta4 - copia.png
```

Something very important about resources in Android: *they cannot contain spaces*. Remove `- copia` from the name of that PNG and it'll compile.